# generating C# code file during Visual Studio build

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have an XML and an XSLT file. The XSLT transforms the XML into a C# file.
What I want to do now is let visual studio generate the .cs file during a pre build event and then compile the project as usual.
Is this even possible? If so, how can this be done?

This is about VS 2013.

Comment: You may have look on [T4 Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh882448.aspx)

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but T4 templates dont seem flexible enough for this purpose. I want to generate classes with code from an xml file. T4 templates look like they are more for getting single values out of an xml file so you can fill in the variables for boilerplate codes in a file

Comment: If you have a *complete code* to, basically,  copy/paste into another file, you may create a small program which from cmdline gets xmlnfile path, parses it with known tags and generate `cs` file. You can launch it in before build action.

Comment: In pre-build event you need command line tool to execute, do you have problems with it? If no, just create a stub for .cs file, include it in your project. It will be changed by your tool in pre-build event and compiled with new text during build.